# How does the voltage go negative on the BJT base in this simple flasher?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, bjt

I'm trying to get more specific in my understanding of electronics, and, like any adult learner, am realizing I have to correct some basic misunderstandings or gaps in my knowledge of fundamentals.

Consider the following flasher circuit. I've paused the current cycle at a point where the voltage on the base of one of the BJTs is negative. I wonder how does this happen? I don't understand how +9v can be dropped over the 100k resistor and the BE junction past 9v. Does the capacitor pull voltage out of the ground in order to balance the charge?

[image]

Comment: What is the software that produced that diagram? What is the large blue block saying -6.73V? Is that with respect to the 9V, i.e. 9V - 6.73V = 2.27V?

Comment: It's iCircuit. -6.73V means -6.73V, not 2.27V. Green is V+, Red V- and Grey is ground. http://icircuitapp.com/

Comment: The voltage on the caps. cannot change instantaneously, so suppose the left Q is off and the right Q on, then the left cap. will charge up to about (9-0.3-0.7)V=8V until the right cap charges enough to turn on the left Q base. When this happens, the right Q base will drop to (0.2-8)V.

Comment: @venny: I'm off by quite a bit, I allowed 0.7 for the base and 0.3 for the LED, I'm guessing the measurement doesn't capture the min and maybe the battery is not quite 9? Time for another glass :-).

Comment: A bit old school of me. I just realised its a simulation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To gain some insight, consider the following simple circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbdUqB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assume the switch has been in the top position for some time such that the voltage across the capacitor is, e.g., 8V with the top terminal the more positive.  The voltage at the anode of the diode is about 0.7V.

Then, the switch is moved to the lower position.

Now the top terminal of the capacitor is connected to the 0V reference so the voltage there is 0V.

But, since there is no path for the capacitor to discharge (the diode blocks any discharge current), the voltage across the capacitor must still be 8V with the top terminal the more positive.

Thus, the anode of the diode (connected to the lower terminal of the capacitor) must now be -8V.

We've produced a negative voltage by first charging the capacitor to a particular voltage and then we *switch* the circuit into a different configuration where the voltage across the capacitor is used to produce a negative voltage.

In your circuit, the left most transistor acts as the switch, grounding the left-most capacitor terminal thus producing a negative voltage on the base of the right-most transistor.

Answer (score 2):

It works like a charge pump. When right transistor is closed, left transistor is open and its base is only about 0.7 V above ground. That will polarize the right capacitor with positive voltage on its right electrode and negative voltage on its left electrode (as shows the picture).

Now when the right transistor opens, which means almost short circuit between collector and emitter, the right positive capacitor electrode is at ground. Which means that its left negative electrode will get below ground level because the voltage across a capacitor is conserved.